# How to save textBox values into a xml-file(with naming an choosing directory)?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

Considering I have a GUI with whatever-many textBoxes, how can i program it, to have a "Save"-button (picture 1), which gives you the the chance to save the xml-file wherever you want on your computer (picture 2), name it (picture 2) then and save the values, you wrote into the boxes?

[photo 1 for better idea of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0XN1.png)

[photo 2 for better idea of what I meann](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTU3u.png)

Comment: Could you explain a little more? What do you want those three textboxes to do?

Comment: So the picture is just a test run to get the main idea how to work with c# and the whole xml-write and save-dialog. Those three text-boxes are just to input values, which are then saved by the save-button in a xml-file. In the real program I have incooperated things such as checkboxes and comboboxes. But since I have very little understandig of C# I created this test to get the hang of it. Do you understand what I mean and where I#m going with this? If not, what can I be more precise about, so you could help me?

Comment: If you can make me understand what you mean, of course I will help you. So you only have three lines of data in your xml? What's your rationale for using three textboxes instead of one richtextbox?

Comment: Yeah I only have three, but this is just to understand the basic structure so I can built the xml-writer into a bigger program with more than 3 textboxes, also including checkboxes and other things. and in this basic program, i thought just taking three basic textboxes to learn how to use c# and the savedialog plus xml-writer would be an easy start. I just can't get to a result. Whatever i tried wouldn't work, thats why I#m asking for help.

Comment: As I did not use a richtextbox in the main program I'm working on, I did not use it in this "learning"-program. The pictures are refering to the program which should help me understand how I can do it, so I can use it on the bigger scale.